# Getting only date from DateTimeField in django

Tags: django-models

I am trying to create a dailylog to my company, so I used dynamic function `DateTimeField` to get the time and date of my location.

From this I need to write validations using date obtained in DateTimeField,
can anyone help me in getting the "date" from the output?

Thank you for the support in advance.

**Forms.py**

```
class employeecheckinform(forms.ModelForm): 
    class Meta: 
        model = Checkin 
        fields=[ 'user', 'employee_ID', 'checkin', ] 

class employeecheckoutform(forms.ModelForm): 
    class Meta: 
        model = Checkout 
        fields=[ 'user', 'employee_ID', 'checkout',]
```

**Models.py**

```
class Checkin(models.Model): 
    user = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete = models.CASCADE ) 
    employee_ID = models.ForeignKey(EmployeeDetails,on_delete = models.CASCADE) 
    checkin = models.DateTimeField(default = timezone.now) 
    checkin1 = datetime.datetime.today()
```

Comment: Consider posting your code. it will help people help you.

Comment: class Checkin(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete = models.CASCADE )
    employee_ID = models.ForeignKey(EmployeeDetails,on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    checkin = models.DateTimeField(default = timezone.now)
    checkin1 = datetime.datetime.today()

Comment: The code I used to create a model is the above specified. I want to get only "date" from the above "checkin" object in the model created

Comment: what do you mean by I want to get only 'date' ?

Comment: The output of DateTimeField in Django is "nov 6 2017 10:43" out of this format i need only "date" as "nov 6"

Answer (score 0):

This is from the [`DateTimeField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/fields/#datetimefield) documentation:

> A date and time, represented in Python by a datetime.datetime instance.
>   Takes the same extra arguments as DateField.

Therefore, you need to change the rendering format of the date in your application. You did not provide much code so I'll provide a general solution but this is how you modify the date format in python using [strftime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) according to your wanted format:

```
import datetime 

print(datetime.datetime.now())
print(datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%b %d'))
```

**Output**

```
2017-11-06 11:06:21.131900
Nov 06
```

**EDIT**

Try this:

```
class employeecheckinform(forms.ModelForm): 
    checkin = DateTimeField(input_formats=["%b %d"])
    class Meta: 
        model = Checkin 
        fields=[ 'user', 'employee_ID', 'checkin', ]
```

Comment: Are you using it in a form ? in the admin ?

Comment: But i need to use that in a model ? can you help me in doing that !

Comment: i am trying to create a "dailylog" for my company . so I am trying to build a checkin and checkout forms. I have to write a validation for the checkout based on the date .

Comment: yes I am creating an account for each user and finally to use the application as a whole . I am logging in as Admin

Comment: class employeecheckinform(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Checkin
        fields=[
            'user',
            'employee_ID',
            'checkin',
            ]


class employeecheckoutform(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Checkout
        fields=[
            'user',
            'employee_ID',
            'checkout',


            ]

Comment: yes I did but I am trying to use it as an entity in models which is not supported as "models.datetime.datetime.now()"

Comment: Sorry I can't help you. Your question is really unclear and your expectations seems to change a lot.

Comment: @ scharette I was trying to post the code , but it says invalid or syntax error . can you help me by telling the procedure to post the code, so then i will post the code

Comment: You edit your question and use the formatting tools.